# Insert a slice of items in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to insert a slice of struct (item) into dynamoDB? Currently, I can only insert one item. Here is how my current function does this.

```
func Insert(doc interface{}) error {
    av, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(doc)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
        Item:      av,
        TableName: "schools",
    }
    _, err = svc.PutItem(input)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

How do I adjust the `Insert` function to insert a slice of items?
`func InsertMulti(doc []interface{}) error {`  - what should be here?

Here is what I have been able to do

```
func InsertMulti (doc []interface{}) error {
    for _, v := range doc {
        av, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(doc)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        


    }
    input := &dynamodb.BatchWriteItemInput{
        RequestItems: map[string][]*dynamodb.WriteRequest{
            "schools" : {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about the [BatchWriter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/#DynamoDB.BatchWriteItem)?

Comment: @Maurice, I think that's it! How do I adopt it into the present function.

Comment: @Maurice I have added what I have done so far.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know go (yet) - I just know how the DynamoDB API works ;-)

Comment: If anybody stuck at the same operation, this guide may help.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/dynamo-example-load-table-items-from-json.html